# Remove mesa make other dependencies uninstalled

Tags: linux, apt, elementary-os

I just run these 2 commands

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/updates
```

And now it uninstall everything on my PC.
I'm using elementary os 5.0 Juno btw.
how to fix this please?